# How do I use a 12V LED indicator light for an alternator ( I have seen some on this, looking for a work around)

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, automotive

I have a dune buggy project and wanted to use a small LED indicator lamp in the charging system. The way it works is, key on, lamp illuminates. Engine starts, power to alternator field, lamp goes out.

My issue is the power coming out of the LED light to the field on the alternator is barely 2 volts. Not enough to energize the field. Is there a work around?

Comment: "Power coming out of the LED light" suggests that there's more to this design than meets the eye, or a misunderstanding somewhere (since power isn't measured in volts). Please add a schematic showing how you have it wired currently, so we can try to diagnose and suggest improvements.

Comment: Most green and red LEDs have a forward voltage of ~2 volts. The indicator lamp you're using likely has a current-limiting resistor in series with the LED making it suitable for use with 12V. Swap out the resistor for something suitable for the voltage you are using. Research "selecting resistor for LED" and you're sure to get lots of information.

Comment: Re-reading your question - are you trying to put the indicator in series with an automotive alternator? As nanofarad said, you should add a schematic. Having "power coming out of the LED..." is a problematic statement.

Comment: It is more important to measure the drop of the regulated alternator voltage on the battery from normal which is 14.2 with it dropping quickly to 13.8 or so when not then slowly decaying to <=12.5V depending on load to battery. Is that correct from your measurements?  Headlights going dimmer at idle is an example.  Then a comparator for battery <13.8 is what I suggest

Comment: You could put either a resistor or a regular indicator bulb in parallel with your LED/resistor. The alternator needs about 250mA to energise the field, so something like a 3W filament bulb is normal.

Comment: And some of us would also tap into that circuit on the alternator side of the indicator light to drive a small relay, to drive a larger one to control charging current to a second battery - which meant the second battery could do lights and music without discharging the main battery.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a typical wiring diagram for an alternator idiot light:

[image]

From here: https://bimmerprofs.com/old-type-alternators/

You'll notice that the indicator is connected between the battery (+) terminal and the field coil supply. What happens is the following:

- Ignition on: current flows from battery (+) through the light to field coil, providing start-up excitation current and lighting the light
- Engine run: Diodes at top right ("Trio") provide field coil current, (+) vs. field difference drops to nearly zero and the light goes out

The issue with using an LED instead of a light bulb is that the LED + dropping resistor combined resistance is too high to provide adequate current to excite the field winding compared to a light bulb.

How to fix it? Place a 50 ohm / 5W shunt resistor in parallel with the LED. This will supply the startup field current before the engine starts. The resistor and LED will only conduct before you start.

I also recommend a reverse-protection diode for the LED in case field voltage rises higher than battery (it might at high RPM or if some other fault happens.)

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWIRl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can modify the shunt resistor as needed if the field coil needs more current to get going, but beware that the resistor will need a bigger power rating as its value gets smaller (P = E^2 / R). Also, note that the resistor will heat up: make sure it isn't near anything that can melt.

What to expect? The field coil resistance is about 5 to 8 ohms (you can check this with an ohmmeter.) With ignition on, engine stopped, battery at 13V, the drop across the 50 ohm resistor will be about 11 volts, and the field coil itself will measure about 2V. As the engine starts, the field coil voltage will rise as the alternator self-excites through the "Trio" diodes and builds up the field. With the engine running, the field coil should measure about 14V, similar to the battery-charging voltage.

Related: [Replacing alternator warning lamp with LED](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196688/replacing-alternator-warning-lamp-with-led)

Comment: moving the  the resistor connection to the other side of the 1N4001 has the advantage that it makes it possible to stop the engine using the ignition switch. by preventing the alternator from powering the ignition though its field rectifier and and the 50 ohm resistor

Comment: Let's assume that problem is solved elsewhere, as having just a light bulb would have the exact same issue (maybe worse.) Good thought though.

Comment: I ownesd one car that had a diode in series with the altenator lamp.

Comment: It wasn't a problem on older cars where the ignition coil needed more current than the warning lamp could provide from the alternator. Modern cars are more likely to just power the ECU or a relay from that supply instead and often need the diode.

Comment: Thanks to all. Sorry for not being more consise and providing a schematic. In short the answers provided have fixed my issue. I have zero ee education other than as basic understanding of circuits. The issue was there was insufficient voltage to energize the alternator. Couldn't understand how the led light could do that. Many thanks to everyone for taking your time to educate me. ( And solve my problem) warm regards, Mike

Comment: If one did not need an indicator light, would it still work to omit the LED (and its resistor) entirely, just using the shunt to provide the necessary current to drive the field?